# parseInt(null, 24) === 23... wait, what?

Tags: javascript, parseint

Alright, so I was messing around with parseInt to see how it handles values not yet initialized and I stumbled upon this gem. The below happens for any radix 24 or above.

```
parseInt(null, 24) === 23 // evaluates to true
```

I tested it in IE, Chrome and Firefox and they all alert true, so I'm thinking it must be in the specification somewhere. A quick Google search didn't give me any results so here I am, hoping someone can explain.

I remember listening to a Crockford speech where he was saying `typeof null === "object"` because of an oversight causing Object and Null to have a near identical type identifier in memory or something along those lines, but I can't find that video now.

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/robert/txjwP/

**Edit** Correction: a higher radix returns different results, 32 returns 785077
**Edit 2** From zzzzBov: `[24...30]:23, 31:714695, 32:785077, 33:859935, 34:939407, 35:1023631, 36:1112745`

---

**tl;dr**

Explain why `parseInt(null, 24) === 23` is a true statement.

Comment: How quirky. JavaScript always keeps you on your toes.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Why does parseInt(null, 24) yield 23, surely that's not supposed to?

Comment: I believe that the question is, "Why does parseInt(null, 24) equal 23 in this case?"

Comment: data point: `alert(parseInt(null, 34) === 23)` produced `false`

Comment: @Stephen P: Right, my bad, forgot, that produces 785077, let me update

Comment: `alert(parseInt(null,26)===23);` also produces true ?!?!

Comment: `[24...30]:23`, `31:714695`, `32:785077`, `33:859935`, `34:939407`, `35:1023631`, `36:1112745`, `[37...]:NaN`

Comment: zzzzBov: parseInt won't handle an radix above 36, but I'll put the other stuff in the question for easier reference.

Comment: @Robert, i forgot that `parseInt` was limited to 36.

Comment: As an additional note, `undefined` as the first parameter returns odd results for the 30's

Comment: @zzzzBov: It shouldn't. Well, it depends how you define "odd".

Answer (score 243, accepted):

It's converting `null` to the string `"null"` and trying to convert it. For radixes 0 through 23, there are no numerals it can convert, so it returns `NaN`. At 24, `"n"`, the 14th letter, is added to the numeral system. At 31, `"u"`, the 21st letter, is added and the entire string can be decoded. At 37 on there is no longer any valid numeral set that can be generated and NaN is returned.

```
js> parseInt(null, 36)
1112745

>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x * 36 + y, [(string.digits + string.lowercase).index(x) for x in 'null'])
1112745
```

Comment: i hadn't even thought about casting null to a string. i'm not aware of any other function that would do that. Good call though, makes perfect sense.

Comment: Not true.  "u" cannot be decoded in base 14 and it trips clause 11 of 15.1.2.2 " If S contains any character that is not a radix-R digit, then let Z be the substring of S consisting of all characters before the first such character; otherwise, let Z be S." so only the "n" part of "null" is ever decoded in base 24.

Comment: No it's not. `toString(null)` is `"[object Window]"` - http://jsfiddle.net/Lf8Yd/.

Comment: @Tomalak: Who says that it's using `toString()`?

Comment: It looks like it's doing something like `"" + valuePassed` as `undefined` starts returning an integer as soon as u as a valid number, at base 31

Comment: @Ignacio, it's not using toString.  It uses the spec builtin `ToString` which is quite different : "When the parseInt function is called, the following steps are taken:
1. Let inputString be ToString(string)."

Comment: @Ignacio: 15.1.2.2/1 in the spec.

Comment: @Mike: Oh, what is `ToString` then?

Comment: @Tomalak, From section 9.8 of the language spec: "The abstract operation ToString converts its argument to a value of type String according to Table 13:"

Comment: @Mike: You're right; see 9.8. @Ignacio: Sorry, downvote removed :)

Comment: @Mike Samuel: It makes sense to me, I'm still here though, if it's wrong whats the right answer?

Comment: @Ignacio.  Actually, I was wrong.  I didn't realize 37 was referring to a radix.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Robert, no I was confused and thought he was claiming something other than what he was claiming.  It's the right answer.  Apologies all around.

Comment: @Mike: 15.1.2.2/8 "If R < 2 or R > 36, then return NaN." ;)

Comment: @Tomalak, yep. Strictly speaking, there's a ToInt32 in there (http://es5.github.com/#x15.1 step 6), so `parseInt('15', 4294967306)` is a counterexample but now I'm splitting hairs :)

Comment: I still think that this answer could do with some references. Although it's entirely correct, it's really just one big assertion...

Comment: @Tomalak - check my answer for all the references. This answer is the correct (and first) one so I think it should remain the accepted one. Although it never hurts to explain what goes on under the hood ;)

Comment: @David: First by five seconds. I don't really think that that's important. Note that I'm not suggesting it should not be the accepted one.

Answer (score 120):

Mozilla [tells us](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> function parseInt **converts its first
>   argument to a string**, parses it, and
>   returns an integer or NaN. If not NaN,
>   the returned value will be the decimal
>   integer representation of the first
>   argument taken as a number in the
>   specified radix (base). For example, a
>   radix of 10 indicates to convert from
>   a decimal number, 8 octal, 16
>   hexadecimal, and so on. For radices
>   above 10, the letters of the alphabet
>   indicate numerals greater than 9. For
>   example, for hexadecimal numbers (base
>   16), A through F are used.

In [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), 15.1.2.2/1 tells us that the conversion to string is performed using the built-in `ToString`, which (as per 9.8) yields `"null"` (not to be confused with `toString`, which would yield `"[object Window]"`!).

So, let's consider `parseInt("null", 24)`.

Of course, this isn't a base-24 numeric string in entirety, but "n" is: it's *decimal 23*.

Now, parsing stops after the decimal 23 is pulled out, because `"u"` *isn't* found in the base-24 system:

> If S contains any character that is
>   not a radix-R digit, then let Z be the
>   substring of S consisting of all
>   characters before the first such
>   character; otherwise, let Z be S. [15.1.2.2/11]

(And this is why `parseInt(null, 23)` (and lower radices) gives you `NaN` rather than 23: `"n"` is not in the base-23 system.)

Comment: This is very tragic behavior of parseInt (I was thinking why it was not design to though exception in these case). I would prefer to use NUMBER() instead when I can.

Answer (score 81):

Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams is correct, but lets see exactly [how it works](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf)...

From `15.1.2.2 parseInt (string , radix)`:

> When the parseInt function is called,
>   the following steps are taken:
>
> - **Let inputString be ToString(string).**
> - Let S be a newly created substring of inputString consisting of the first
>     character that is not a
>     StrWhiteSpaceChar and all characters
>     following that character. (In other
>     words, remove leading white space.)
> - Let sign be 1.
> - If S is not empty and the first character of S is a minus sign -, let
>     sign be −1.
> - If S is not empty and the first character of S is a plus sign + or a
>     minus sign -, then remove the first
>     character from S.
> - Let R = ToInt32(radix).
> - Let stripPrefix be true.
> - If R ≠ 0, then a. If R < 2 or R > 36, then return NaN. b. If R ≠ 16, let
>     stripPrefix be false.
> - Else, R = 0 a. Let R = 10.
> - If stripPrefix is true, then a. If the length of S is at least 2 and the
>     first two characters of S are either
>     “0x” or “0X”, then remove the first
>     two characters from S and let R = 16.
> - **If S contains any character that is not a radix-R digit, then let Z be the
>     substring of S consisting of all
>     characters before the first such
>     character; otherwise, let Z be S.**
> - If Z is empty, return NaN.
> - Let mathInt be the mathematical integer value that is represented by Z
>     in radix-R notation, using the letters
>     A-Z and a-z for digits with values 10
>     through 35. (However, if R is 10 and Z
>     contains more than 20 significant
>     digits, every significant digit after
>     the 20th may be replaced by a 0 digit,
>     at the option of the implementation;
>     and if R is not 2, 4, 8, 10, 16, or
>     32, then mathInt may be an
>     implementation-dependent approximation
>     to the mathematical integer value that
>     is represented by Z in radix-R
>     notation.)
> - Let number be the Number value for mathInt.
> - Return sign × number.
>
> **NOTE parseInt may interpret only a
>   leading portion of string as an
>   integer value; it ignores any
>   characters that cannot be interpreted
>   as part of the notation of an integer,
>   and no indication is given that any
>   such characters were ignored.**

There are two important parts here. I bolded both of them. So first of all, we have to find out what the `toString` representation of `null` is. We need to look at `Table 13 — ToString Conversions` in section 9.8.0 for that information:

[image]

Great, so now we know that doing `toString(null)` internally yields a `'null'` string. Great, but how exactly does it handle digits (characters) that aren't valid within the radix provided?

We look above to `15.1.2.2` and we see the following remark:

> If S contains any character that is
>   not a radix-R digit, then let Z be the
>   substring of S consisting of all
>   characters before the first such
>   character; otherwise, let Z be S.

That means that we handle all digits PRIOR to the specified radix and ignore everything else.

Basically, doing `parseInt(null, 23)` is the same thing as `parseInt('null', 23)`. The `u` causes the two `l`'s to be ignored (even though they ARE part of the radix 23). Therefore, we only can only parse `n`, making the entire statement synonymous to `parseInt('n', 23)`. :)

Either way, great question!

Answer (score 34):

```
parseInt( null, 24 ) === 23
```

Is equivalent to

```
parseInt( String(null), 24 ) === 23
```

which is equivalent to

```
parseInt( "null", 24 ) === 23
```

The digits for base 24 are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, b, c, d, e, f, ..., n.

The language spec says

> 1. If S contains any character that is not a radix-R digit, then let Z be the substring of S consisting of all characters before the first such character; otherwise, let Z be S.

which is the part that ensures that C-style integer literals like `15L` parse properly,
so the above is equivalent to

```
parseInt( "n", 24 ) === 23
```

`"n"` is the 23-rd letter of the digit list above.

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 16):

I guess `null` gets converted to a string `"null"`. So `n` is actually `23` in 'base24' (same in  'base25'+), `u` is invalid in 'base24' so the rest of the string `null` will be ignored. That's why it outputs `23` until `u` will become valid in 'base31'.

Answer (score 7):

parseInt uses alphanumeric representation, then in base-24 "n" is valid, but "u" is invalid character, then parseInt only parses the value "n"....

```
parseInt("n",24) -> 23
```

as an example, try with this:

```
alert(parseInt("3x", 24))
```

The result will be "3".