# Jquery custom validation non numeric

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to write a custom validation function for jquery. The rule should be that the field cannot ONLY be numeric. I know how to write only numeric or only alpha but I want the rule to say that a value of "12345" would fail, but "12345A" would be validated

This is what I have for non numeric

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("nonNumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || !value.match(/[0-9]+/);
},"Only alphabatic characters allowed.");
```

but I can't figure out how to do not ONLY numeric.

---

**Working script**

Here are three rules that might be helpful, the last one is the one that answers this question.

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) { 
    return value.indexOf(" ") < 0 && value != ""; 
}, "No spaces please");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("alpha", function(value, element) {

    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
},"Letters only please.");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("nonNumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || isNaN(Number(value));
},"String cannot be numeric");
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want that the value contains at least on numerical and one alphabetical character?

Comment: No basically its for a username field, but I don't want users to type in an integer to try to mimic a userid. So it needs atleast one alphabetical char, it just can't be all numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parseInt` (which returns NaN if the operand isn't strictly a number) like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("nonNumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(parseInt(value));
},"Only alphabatic characters allowed.");
```

Don't use `!=` in this case or you could wind up with [this unpleasant situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459758/parseintnull-24-23-wait-what).

---

According to **Ken Browning**'s comment, `parseInt` might not be appropriate here. Try this instead:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("nonNumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(Number(value));
},"Only alphabatic characters allowed.");
```

Comment: parseInt probably isn't appropriate here: ​alert(!!​parseInt('3x'))​​​​​​​

Comment: Mm, that's true, I'll edit with another option. I'm not 100% positive but `Number` should do the trick. Can't pull the double not trick here. :p

Comment: I think the OP wants the input to be valid if at least one character is alphabetical.., but I'm not sure. Btw, you cannot use the comparison operator for testing against `NaN`, use `isNaN()`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yep, that's what this'll do, unless I somehow reversed my logic and it's only returning if input is invalid, because if `Number(value)` equals NaN that means there's a letter in there somewhere.

Comment: Ah right... now I understand...I would probably have used something like `/[a-z]/.test(value)`. Or use `!isNaN(+value)`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Nice, nice nice. I'm no JS expert (yet) so this is the best I've got. =)

Comment: I corrected your code... even if `Number('123foo')` returns `NaN`, `Number('123foo') != NaN` is `false`, simply because `NaN` is not equal to any value, not even to itself.

Comment: @FelixKling: Oops, that's right... and I just read that somewhere, too. Thanks!

Comment: The edit was mostly correct except for the not ! was reversed as mentioned. I'll add the custom rules up top incase people come across this

Answer (score 1):

change your regular expression to this:

```
(/.*[a-zA-Z]+.*/)
```

on your code:

EDIT 1:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("nonNumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.match(/.*[a-zA-Z]+.*/);
},"Only alphabatic characters allowed.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
/[a-z]/i.test(value)
```

which returns `true` if `value` contains any letter between a and z.

The `i` modifier makes the test case insensitive.

For more information about `.test()`, have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Answer (score 1):

I think this regex should be enough

```
/[a-z]/i.test(value);
```

Usage

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("nonNumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || !(/[a-zA-Z]/i.test(value));
},"Only alphabatic characters allowed.");
```

Comment: You don't need `A-Z` if you are using the `i` modifier... that's the whole point of it ;)

Comment: This doesn't help for non ascii characters